# UDP/TCP connection over Wifi interrupted for a few seconds on Android 9 and higher

Tags: android

I have a device that streams data with an Android app over wifi. The app connects to the device's wifi directly and does not have internet access.

The problem is that eventually this stream is paused by Android, leaving a few seconds inactive. The WIFI connection does not go down, it remains active, but the data does not reach the app.

I tried TCP and UDP to exchange data. In the case of UDP, packets are simply lost. While in TCP the OS seems to buffer the data, and when the communication returns I get everything at once ... So the socket remains active, but apparently the network layer communication between the app and the OS that is interrupted.

And for my application I can't go without the connection for a long time, I need the information in real time.

I realized this only occurs on Android 9 or higher. However, I obtained different disconnection times on two different devices with Android 9. On the Samsung T290 Tab the disconnection remains for more than 15 seconds in some cases, on the Samsung T395 Tab it does not exceed 5 seconds.

Logcat of these two devices when this happens:

```
Samsung T395:
10-20 18:55:45.904  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false
10-20 18:55:46.305  5144  5144 I chatty  : uid=10137(com.sec.android.inputmethod) identical 2 lines
10-20 18:55:46.505  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false
10-20 18:55:46.689  3348  3502 D WifiTrafficPoller: TrafficStats TxPkts=25813 RxPkts=25268 TxBytes=1051795 RxBytes=2098768 , Foreground uid=10175 pkgName=MDT_Sm.MDT_Sm TxPackets=19912 RxPackets=19921 TxBytes=577605 RxBytes=1772669
10-20 18:55:46.706  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false
10-20 18:55:47.308  5144  5144 I chatty  : uid=10137(com.sec.android.inputmethod) identical 3 lines
10-20 18:55:47.509  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false
10-20 18:55:47.552  3348  3503 D WifiStateMachine: enter getWifiLinkLayerStats
10-20 18:55:47.553  3348  3503 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3095) before calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
10-20 18:55:47.554  2853  2853 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: enter getLinkLayerStats
10-20 18:55:47.554  2853  2853 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: enter getLinkLayerStatsInternal
10-20 18:55:47.560  2853  2853 I android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: Successfully getLinkLayerStats.
10-20 18:55:47.561  3348  3503 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3095) after calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
10-20 18:55:47.710  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false
10-20 18:55:49.593  4322  4322 D io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 36875 2262380 w 38811 512820 d 2559 51108 f 12046 12045 iot 39190 41358 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 11153.704
10-20 18:55:49.916  5144  5144 I chatty  : uid=10137(com.sec.android.inputmethod) identical 11 lines
10-20 18:55:50.117  5144  5144 I SKBD    : alm isTosAccept false


Samsung T290:
08-31 16:48:51.768  1082  1307 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3095) after calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
08-31 16:48:52.702  1880  1880 D io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 112440 5417329 w 28758 442000 d 2111 76764 f 7730 11484 iot 137220 133696 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 12526.730
08-31 16:48:53.343  1396  1396 D NetworkController: updateCarrierText : MSC_9319320495
08-31 16:48:53.344  1396  1396 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: updateCarrierTextInfo
08-31 16:48:53.346  1396  1396 D KeyguardClockPage: isNetworkRoamingState id=-2
08-31 16:48:53.346  1396  1396 D KeyguardClockPage: isNetworkRoamingState false
08-31 16:48:53.346  1396  1396 D KeyguardClockPage: onRefreshCarrierInfo(pre, now): false, false
08-31 16:48:53.346  1396  1396 D CarrierText: updateCarrierText(): 0
08-31 16:48:53.347  1396  1396 D CarrierText: Getting plmn/spn/subId sticky brdcst  plmn : Sem servi├ºo, spn : , subId :-2
08-31 16:48:53.347  1396  1396 D CarrierText: plmn Of NetworkController Impl : MSC_9319320495
08-31 16:48:53.347  1396  1396 D CarrierText: BLOCK_CARRIER_TEXT_WHEN_SIM_NOT_READY or KOR_USIM_TEXT
08-31 16:48:53.347  1396  1396 D CarrierText: setText :
08-31 16:48:53.460   572   572 I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
08-31 16:48:53.460   572   572 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 1 line
08-31 16:48:53.461   572   572 I ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
08-31 16:48:54.778  1082  1307 D WifiStateMachine: enter getWifiLinkLayerStats
08-31 16:48:54.778  1082  1307 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3095) before calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
08-31 16:48:54.812  1082  1307 I WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.3095) after calling iface.getLinkLayerStats
08-31 16:48:55.224   410   410 W hwservicemanager: getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.samsung.hardware.radio.channel@1.0::ISecChannel/imsd in either framework or device manifest.
08-31 16:48:57.705  1880  1880 D io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 112440 5417329 w 28761 442016 d 2111 76764 f 7730 11484 iot 137270 133747 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 12531.733
```

Would anyone know to tell me why this is happening and if it is possible to fix this problem?

Thank you.